# Drupal root directory from development

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

I just put a drupal 8 site online.
I developed this site in folder 'snew'.
The online site refers to that folder and drupal expects the files to be in this sub folder.
So everything refers to:
www.domain.com/snew/
And it should be the root of the website:
www.domain.com

How can i change this?

Answer (score 2):

For most of my installs, I have Drupal running from subfolders. Here is what I do:
settings.php
Uncomment and modify this line:

```
# $base_url = 'http://www.example.com';  // NO trailing slash!
```

.htaccess (in your subfolder)
Unless there are server/web host-specific items to add, this can be left alone

.htaccss (in Web root)

Options -Indexes

```
RewriteEngine on
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.[yourdomain]\.[your TLD]$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* http://www..[yourdomain].[your TLD]/ [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^$ production/index.php [L]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/[subfolder]%{REQUEST_URI} -f
RewriteRule .* [subfolder]/$0 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .*[subfolder]/index.php?q=$0 [QSA]
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: @Nomistake – Please don't post link-only comments. What is it you want to tell us with that link?

Comment: @leymannx, ok. I developped my site on the root of my xampp and when i uploaded the site it was fine...
So there is no real tested answer.